# "using/driving" to point out the method

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

> Sabre HQ is 30 minutes away ***driving*** the speed limit.
>
> An on-screen keyboard allows people with mobility impairments to type
> data ***using*** a joystick or a pointing device.

Hi. I am not sure if the marked verbs can be defined as participles. If they are, can we say they are dangling participles? Since Sabre HQ is not driving or an on-screen keybord is not using a joystick. If they are not participles, how do we call them? or is there a special name for this usage?

Comment: Both examples seem to involve ellipsis, the omission of a word or phrase. Insertion of “when you are” before “driving” makes clear that “driving is a participle in a verb in a progressive tense. Insertion of “by” before “typing” means that we are using the participle as a gerund.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Thank you. Are these sentences grammatically correct as they are? For example: would you lose marks, if you used them in an article on an exam?

Comment: This is question of style rather than grammar. Style sheets differ, but most allow ellipsis. I doubt you would get a bad mark although you might be asked to re-write according to the controlling style manual. Personally, I would insert “if” before “driving and “by” before “typing” because I feel they ease comprehension.

Comment: I would say _driving at the speed limit_.

Comment: @KateBunting - I have heard (mainly Americans) say e.g. 'I was going thirty'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I don't see anything wrong with _going thirty_, but _driving the speed limit_ struck me as decidedly odd.

Comment: Context (not given) is that this is dialogue from Season 8 Episode 15 of the US version of the TV series 'The Office' - _Dwight: Today is the first day of Sabre’s new project to develop a chain of retail stores. I am meeting my new boss, Nellie Bertram, head of special projects. Work starts at nine. Sabre HQ is thirty minutes away, driving the speed limit. Giving everyone twenty minutes to shower, plus fifty for Jim to style his hair, twenty for breakfast, forty for Erin to get lost between her room and the lobby, ninety for Ryan to do his morning ecstasy… We’re already twenty minutes late._

Comment: @JeffMorrow Thank you. I think it is clear which nouns they modify but as far as I know rule (grammarbank.com/reducing-adverbial-clauses.html) says: "the subjects of the two sentences should be the same". In the example above "Sabre is the main subject" while the subject of driving is "unkown" but for sure not Sabre HQ . I just don't understand when they are considered dangling participles.

Answer (score 0):

Context (not given) is that this is dialogue from Season 8 Episode 15 of the US version of the TV series 'The Office'. Omission of 'at' before 'the speed limit' could be US regional or informal speech, or else careless editing or copying.

> Dwight: Today is the first day of Sabre’s new project to develop a
> chain of retail stores. I am meeting my new boss, Nellie Bertram, head
> of special projects. Work starts at nine. Sabre HQ is thirty minutes
> away, driving the speed limit. Giving everyone twenty minutes to
> shower, plus fifty for Jim to style his hair, twenty for breakfast,
> forty for Erin to get lost between her room and the lobby, ninety for
> Ryan to do his morning ecstasy… We’re already twenty minutes late. –

Comment: Thank you. I think it is clear which nouns they modify but as far as I know rule (https://www.grammarbank.com/reducing-adverbial-clauses.html) says: "the subjects of the two sentences should be the same". In the example above "Sabre is the main subject" while the subject of driving is "unkown" but for sure not Sabre HQ . I just don't understand when they are considered dangling participles.